# Pandas aggregate by year and month and sum other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

Having the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'x': ['2019-07-29', '2019-07-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-03'],
    'y': [4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['x', 'y'])
df
```

This will output:

```
    x   y
0   2019-07-29  4
1   2019-07-30  6
2   2019-07-31  4
3   2019-08-01  4
4   2019-08-02  6
5   2019-08-03  7
```

Is it possible to group the dates in column x by year and month and sum the amounts in x and place the result in a new dataframe? Like so:

```
    x   y
0   2019-07  13
1   2019-08  17
```

Comment: In theory this is resampling: `df.resample('M', on='x').sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert `x` to pandas datetime. Then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on [`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
In [181]: df.x = pd.to_datetime(df.x)
In [194]: df = df.groupby([df.x.dt.year, df.x.dt.month]).agg(sum).rename_axis(['year', 'month']).reset_index().rename(columns={'y':'sum'})

In [195]: df
Out[195]: 
   year  month  sum
0  2019      7   14
1  2019      8   17
```

Comment: What is the easiest method to reconstruct the date? Is it required to set the day to 1 for example?

Comment: Just do `df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['month'].astype(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['x'].str[:-3])['y'].sum()
x
2019-07    14
2019-08    17
```